# What type of ssl certifcates are acceptable?

Tags: android, ssl

I need a secured connection between the client(Android application) and server. I referred official document developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html. And also found here globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/… that there are three types of ssl certificate:

1. Extended Validation (EV SSL) Certificates
2. Organization Validated (OV
   SSL) Certificates
3. Domain Validated (DV SSL) Certificates

Which of the above supported in android app?(not in the browser.I am using retrofit to call web services), And Which one should I use?

Comment: All of these are supported.

Comment: Hello @Steffen Ullrich, I am talking about android mobile application. I need a secured connection between client and server.
I referred official document https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html.
And also found here https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/types-of-ssl-certificate/ that there are three types of ssl certificate:
1)Extended Validation Certificates
2)Organization Validated Certificates,
3)Domain Validated Certificates
My question is which of the above supported in android app (not in the browser).And Which should I use?

Comment: Again, all of these are supported. They don't actually differ much from the technical site. You could probably use the cheapest one since the only thing an EV certificate provides for the client is a nice green bar in the browser - which you'll probably don't have in your Android app anyway.

Comment: Please stop re-adding the `[android]` tag to your question title. Tags belong to the tag area **only**.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Steffen Ullrich, any of the listed SSL certificates will work for your purposes.  The primary difference between those options that you have listed is the extent to which the certificate authority will go to in order to verify your identity.

The scrutiny given to any certificate request can range from very little (no verification beyond domain name ownership) to the requester needing to provide the CA with proof of a physical location.

For your purposes, encrypting traffic from an android application to an API, any of the listed cert types would work and I would go with the cheapest option.

I would recommend: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/ to get what you need.

Additionally, just to add some more context to your question and your specific Android tag.  It actually has little to do with Android and more to do with the server you'll be communicating to.  Getting an SSL cert installed on your server means that you'll be able to encrypt traffic from any source to that server and the only thing you'll need to do from an android perspective is to ensure you hit port 443 (https://)